# Use of thread to interrupt a recursive function inside a jFrame class

Tags: java, multithreading, jform

I currently have a jFrame window in which one of the buttons executes a long time-taking recursive function.

What I want, is that when I click on another button of the window, the program stops the execution of the function.

Here's my code:

```
 public class CrawlerInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame 
 {
       public CrawlerInterface() 
       {
           initComponents();
       }

    private void playButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {

       playButton.setEnabled(false);
       stopButton.setEnabled(true);

       Crawler.crawl("http://www.mywebsite.com", "site"); //That's the one to interrupt
    }

    private void stopButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {
       stopButton.setEnabled(false);
       playButton.setEnabled(true);

       //Interrupt crawl function here!
    }
    [...]
 }
```

How can I modify the above code to do so using a thread? If there is a way to do so without the use of threads, please tell me!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Still, how do I use them here?

Comment: SwingWorker to be more precise. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Answer (score 0):

If your run your code in a background thread (perfectly fine as long as it does not touch any UI components) you can `interrupt` the thread. Or set a boolean variable to use as base condition to stop the recursion.I.e. once you enter the method and the variable is set then stop recursion.
Here is a sample to start with

```
private static volatile boolean stop = false;  

public static void stop(){  
   stop = true;  
}  

public void Crawler.crawl(String url, String word){  
    if(stop) return;
    else{ ... //recurce}  
}  



private void playButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{

       playButton.setEnabled(false);
       stopButton.setEnabled(true);

       Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){  
              @Override  
              public void run(){  
                    Crawler.crawl("http://www.mywebsite.com", "site"); //That's the one to interrupt  
               }  
        });  
        t.start();  
}  


 private void stopButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {
       stopButton.setEnabled(false);
       playButton.setEnabled(true);

       Crawler.stop();  //or you could keep reference to t and call interrupt
    }
```

Comment: Sure, but please, give me some code. I tried a lot of things, but I got lost with notions of runnable classes, run methods...etc. :(

Comment: I couldn't write it here because it's too long, but it's an unthreaded recursive function that crawls a website and writes all of its articles in txt files in a specific folder.

Comment: Is doing this right?
`t = new Thread() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Crawler.crawl("http://www.mywebsite.com", "site");
            }
        };
        t.start();` and in stopButton `t.interrupt();`